# Magnitude of a vector?

Tags: calculus

This is a really stupid question but how do i calculate the magnitude of a vector? 
I understand how to do it for basic values such as <4,2> etc, you just use Pythagoras.

But for the likes of vector functions such as <2t,3sin(2t),3cos(2t)> I am confused about where all the numbers come from. The answer says 2√10.

Example 1: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/VectorArcLength.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of a vector $(v_1,\ldots, v_n)$ is $$||(v_1,\ldots, v_n)||=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n{v_i^2}\right)^{1/2}$$

Thus, for the example vector $v=(2t,3\sin 2t, 3\cos 2t)$, we have $||v||^2=4t^2+9\cos^2 2t+9\sin^2 2t=4t^2+9$.  Thus, the answer you gave above is incorrect.

It is a little hard to read on the website you provided, but the writer is actually finding the magnitude of $\vec{r}^t$, the tangent vector; this is why he gets a different answer than the one above.

The writer has $\vec{r}^t=(2,6\cos 2t, -6\sin 2t)$.  Then $||\vec{r}^t||^2=4+36\cos^2 2t + 36\sin^2 2t=4+36(\cos^2 2t+\sin^2 2t)=4+36=40=2^2\cdot 10$. Thus, square rooting gives us $2\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Thanks for this, but that is what I wanted, the magnitude of the tangent vector.

Comment: Okay, make sure you're considering the right vector.

Comment: Are you able to explain where the 2√10 came from? Thats what I'm confused about.

Comment: See the edited question.